# how read with datareader from datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datareader

I have a function that returns a DataTable

```
DataTable dt = GetAllObject(ogj_id);
```

Now I want to fill one  MultiCheckCombo, below is the link where I got this MultiCheckCombo

[MultiCheckCombo Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66572/A-Multiple-Selection-DropDownList-a-CheckBoxList-I)

The example of how to fill this MultiCheckCombo from link above is only with dataReader

```
OdbcConnection con = "get YOUR connection string";
con.Open();
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "select text,id from ...........";
OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
MultiCheckCombo1.ClearAll();
dr.Read(); 
MultiCheckCombo1.AddItems(dr, "text", "id");
```

**Query** - Now my question sounds like this: How to convert `DataTable` in `dataReader` to fill this `MultiCheckCombo`?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't have a great interface. You may be better off using the arraylist method but that doesn't seem to allow you to specify text and id separately. I'd suggest modifying their code to allow some kind of enumerable to be passed in that would then be used as a datasource... That doesn't really answer your question though. :)

Comment: There's no such thing as converting a `DataTable` to a `DataReader`. They are different things, used in different situations.

Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Behind the scenes I think .NET uses a `DataReader` to populate a `DataTable`.  You would essentially be converting from one to the other and back again :)

Comment: @dana: .NET can do this but you can quite easily have a DataTable that hasn't ever been anywhere near a DataReader. anderson.pimentel: they are different but there is no reason why you shouldn't be able to expose the information in a DataTable in an object with an IDataReader interface or similar. Its just not very sensible. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a different control.  That one is hard-coded to using an `OdbcDataReader`.  You don't use a `DataReader` to read data from a `DataTable` - you iterate through the `DataRows`.

As a workaround, you could overload AddItems to accept a DataTable:

```
public void AddItems(DataTable dt, string textField, string valueField)
{
    ClearAll();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        chkList.Items.Add(dr[textField].ToString());
        chkList.Items[i].Value = dr[valueField].ToString(); 
        i++;               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert a data reader to a data table. You'll have to loop over the contents of the table and build each item manually. I am not familiar with this particular control, but if it follows normal conventions, it should probably look something like this:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    MultiCheckCombo1.Items.Add(new ListItem(dt["text"], dt["id"]));
}
```